# How to print list of objects grouped by itertools' groupby?

Tags: python, group-by, itertools-groupby

I have a class with some fields. I created a list of objects of this class and now I want to group the list by one of the fields inside the objects. It *almost* works, but unfortunately it shows me only one Dog, but the result for this data should be different.

The code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
from itertools import chain
from itertools import groupby

class Animal:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name,
        age,
        description,
        width,
        height
    ):
        self.data = dict(
            name=name,
            age=age,
            description=description,
            width=width,
            height=height
        )
        for k, v in self.data.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.data)
        
        
animals = [Animal('Dog', '3', 'nice dog', 12, 13), Animal('Cat', '2', 'kitty', 12, 23), Animal('Dog', '5', 'woof', 12, 13)]

# print(vulns)

sorted_animals = sorted(animals, key=lambda Animal: Animal.name)
grouped_animals = [list(result) for key, result in groupby(
    sorted_animals, key=lambda Animal: Animal.name)]
    
report = {"data": OrderedDict(), "meta": {"animals": {}}}

# print(grouped)
for group in grouped_animals:
    for animal in group:
        report["meta"]["animals"][animal.name] = animal.name, animal.age, animal.width
print(report)
```

The result:

`{'data': OrderedDict(), 'meta': {'animals': {'Cat': ('Cat', '2', 12), 'Dog': ('Dog', '5', 12)}}}`

What I want:

`{'data': OrderedDict(), 'meta': {'animals': {'Cat': ('Cat', '2', 12), 'Dog': ('Dog', '5', 12), 'Dog': ('Dog', '3', 12)}}}`

So I'm missing the first animal (`('Dog', '3', 'nice dog', 12, 13)`) in my list. How to solve this?

Comment: What you want is not a valid dict: `{'Cat': ('Cat', '2', 12), 'Dog': ('Dog', '5', 12), ('Dog', '3', 12)}`

Comment: @blhsing OK, so how can I do something similar to this? I mean it can even be: `{'data': OrderedDict(), 'meta': {'animals': {'Cat': ('Cat', '2', 12), 'Dog': ('Dog', '5', 12), 'Dog': ('Dog', '3', 12)}}}`. I edited my question.

Comment: That is not a valid dict either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code as alternative:

```
report = {"data": OrderedDict(), "meta": {"animals": defaultdict(list)}}

for group in grouped_animals:
    for animal in group:
        report["meta"]["animals"][animal.name].append((animal.name, animal.age, animal.width))
```

Output:

```
>>> report
{'data': OrderedDict(),
 'meta': {'animals': defaultdict(list,
              {'Cat': [('Cat', '2', 12)],
               'Dog': [('Dog', '3', 12), ('Dog', '5', 12)]})}}
```

Comment: You might as well skip the whole sort/groupby part and just iterate over `animals` directly and let the dict code handle grouping naturally, too.